# How to merge two dataframes by cross referencing multiple columns when only one is true?

Tags: r

Currently I have two data frames. The first data frame has a column of values that I want to cross reference with multiple columns in the second data frame. There will be a match between the two data frames but the column which contains this match can vary between rows of data.

I tried the `merge()` function with little success, trying:

```
merge(....by.y("A"|"B"))
```

Where A and B reflect column names in data frame number 2.

I have searched this problem quite extensively but unfortunately I have failed to find a solution. Any help will be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Please post some toy data that replicates the structure of your actual data and show the result you want. The description you've given isn't specific enough to work from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speculating on what your data actually looks like:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(id = letters[1:6], V1 = 1:6)
#   id V1
# 1  a  1
# 2  b  2
# 3  c  3
# 4  d  4
# 5  e  5
# 6  f  6

df_2 <- data.frame(
  A = c(NA, "d", NA, NA, "e", "foo", "a", "j"), 
  B = c("i", "foo", NA, NA, NA, "b", "c", "f"), 
  V2 = 11:18
)
#      A    B V2
# 1 <NA>    i 11
# 2    d  foo 12
# 3 <NA> <NA> 13
# 4 <NA> <NA> 14
# 5    e <NA> 15
# 6  foo    b 16
# 7    a    c 17
# 8    j    f 18
```

You could for instance merge with each column separately, then `rbind()`:

```
rbind(
  subset(merge(df_1, df_2, by.x = "id", by.y = "A"), select = - B),
  subset(merge(df_1, df_2, by.x = "id", by.y = "B"), select = - A)
)
#   id V1 V2
# 1  a  1 17
# 2  d  4 12
# 3  e  5 15
# 4  b  2 16
# 5  c  3 17
# 6  f  6 18
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this.